# Installing a package that is in a different .NET target

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

Currently I have a .NET 4.5 project, Project "X". I want to install a package that targets (is written on top of) .Net 4.5.2, Project "Y".

Is there a way where I don't have to update Project-X to 4.5.2 and still install the Project-Y? The reason I don't want to update X is because I have several other projects in the solution that targets it and would prefer not to have to update my entire solution to 4.5.2.

Comment: Are you able to change the target of ProjectY to 4.5 by chance?  That would be a quick and dirty way to do it, but it assumes you own ProjectY.  Or you could use a prior version of Y, perhaps.

Comment: Unfortunately no prior version of Project-Y exists(I believe) - the team that supports the package only builds on top of one version of .NET. I could put a request to the team to support .Net 4.5 but they'll come across the same issue in that they'll have to update all their projects/packages to a lower version -- I'm quite certain they're going to tell me to update my version.

Comment: You pay the price of being on an old version that no packages like that can be consumed.